# LINQ to validate outline numbering (1.1, 1.2, etc)

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently using a normal looping to check if the list of numbers are in order.

I am currently learning LINQ and I want to know how can I implement in LINQ to check if the sequence of numbers are in correct order.

For example I have this list of sequence number:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.4
2.0
```

The program needs to flag as error the line 1.4 because 1.3 is missing.

How can I achieve that using LINQ?

Thanks for all your help. :)

It's like table of contents:

1.1 followed by 1.3 is invalid, 1 followed by 2 is valid. 1.4 followed by 2 is valid.

Here's the code that I am using it still has a lot of lapses I think:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("D:\\test.txt"))
{
    double prevNumber = 0;

    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        double curNumber = double.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
        double x = Math.Round(curNumber - prevNumber, 1);

        if (x == 0.1)
        {
            prevNumber = curNumber;
        }

        else
        {
            int prev = (int)Math.Floor(prevNumber);
            int cur = (int)Math.Floor(curNumber);

            if ((cur - prev) == 1)
            {
                prevNumber = curNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                //error found
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your normal looping code? Paste it here.

Comment: Why are 1.5, 1.6, etc. not considered to be missing? Could there be a number like 1.11? If so, would it come between 1.1 and 1.2 or after 1.9 and 1.10?

Comment: Your question is confusing - the values are in the right *order*, but they're apparently *incomplete*. Those are two very different properties. Please edit your question to give more precise requirements.

Comment: @JRC You might want to rename thus question - it seems you're not really concerned about order but about... contiguity or something.

Comment: BTW, I don't see what should be wrong about a *normal loop*. LINQ is powerful, sure, but it is no silver bullet that solves *every* problem.

Comment: Edited title to more accurately reflect the intent. However, the "normal looping" code would be helpful to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method takes a filename and returns an array of line numbers of incorrect versions. For your example it returns `{ 4 }`.

It only handles numbers of the form `x.y`, as that appears to be all you want it to handle.

```
static int[] IncorrectLines(string filename)
{
    // Parse the file into an array of ints, 10* each version number.
    var ints =  File.ReadLines(filename)
        .Select(s => (int)(10 * decimal.Parse(s))).ToArray();
    // Pair each number up with the previous one.
    var pairs = ints
        .Zip(ints.Skip(1), (p, c) => new { Current = c, Previous = p });
    // Include the line numbers
    var withLineNos = pairs
        .Select((pair, index) => new { Pair = pair, LineNo = index + 2 });
    // Only keep incorrect lines
    var incorrect = withLineNos.Where(o => ! (         // not one of either:
            o.Pair.Current - 1 == o.Pair.Previous ||   // simple increment
            (o.Pair.Current % 10 == 0 &&               // major increment
             (o.Pair.Current / 10) - 1 == o.Pair.Previous / 10)
        ));
    return incorrect.Select(o => o.LineNo).ToArray();
}
```

Honestly? I think you're better off with a loop.

Comment: Man, you hit what I really need!! This is awesome! New learning for tonight! Thanks for this!

Comment: Rawling, this method didn't handle the wholeNumbers? It only the numbers with decimal, how can I make it handle also the wholenumbers?

Comment: @JRC How do you mean? You mean it doesn't break if you put in (1.0, 3.0) say?

Comment: I tried the file containing 
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
and it didn't find the error.

Comment: @JRC I see what you mean. Edited so now it should stop that, and also stop e.g. `1.4 3.0` or `1.0 3.0`.

Comment: It supposed to find only 1 error right? But why it finds numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 as incorrect lines? :(

Comment: @JRC For what input? In your question you put `The program needs to flag as error the line...` so I assumed you might want to show _all_ lines that were a problem... If not, you can just look at the first element of the returned array.

Comment: for this input: 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: I just get `4`; are you sure you've copied the `incorrect` code block properly?

Comment: Yeap, I'm sure, this is what my filepath's data per line: 1.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0.... And the lines that it gets as errors are lines 2, 3, 4 and 5.. I don't know what's wrong. :(

Comment: Oh my bad Rawling! I'm using a wrong file LOL, sorry sorry! thanks man! this is great!

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to loop through a sorted list of doubles (with precision of one decimal place) and determine whether or not -- if decimal places exist for a whole number -- that their difference is not greater than 0.1.

We'll assume your list is sorted:

```
List<double> contents = new List<double>() {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 2.0};
```

You would call IsValid on that list:

```
bool IsValid(List<double> contents) {
  //Get the distinct whole numbers
  var wholeNumbers = contents.Select(t => Math.Floor(t)).Distinct();
  foreach (var num in wholeNumbers) {

    //Get the "subcontents" for this whole number (chapter)
    var subContents = contents.Where(t => Math.Floor(t) == num).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < subContents.Count() - 1; i++) {

      //If the subcontents are different by something other than 0.1, it's invalid
      if (subContents.Count() > 1 && Math.Round(subContents[i + 1] - subContents[i], 1) != 0.1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

(Note that if the subcategories were 1.14, 1.24, 1.34, etc, it would still consider that valid.)

Comment: I test this method, but it always returns true, but anyway I get your point here, and you give me a good hint on what I need to do, thanks Doc! :)

Comment: Try again, I edited it and tested it.  Should work now.  For some reason I had to round the subContents[i + 1] - subContents[i] to one decimal place.

Comment: This doesn't mind if the major versions are completely out of order, as long as the minor versions for each are in order. It doesn't mind if `1.4` is followed by `2.1`.  It iterates through the input far more often than just calling `GroupBy(d => Math.Floor(d))`.